# Errors while building react-native app with Expo

Tags: android, react-native, deployment, build, build.gradle

I try to build my expo app on android platform so I had this error while building.

So when I run eas build --platform android this appear in the log:

> Specifying "android.package" in app.json is deprecated for bare
> workflow projects. EAS Build depends only on the value in the native
> code. Please remove the deprecated configuration.

and here is the log of Run gradlew bellow:

> [stderr]  FAILURE: [stderr]  Build failed with an exception. [stderr]
>
> - Where: [stderr]  Build file '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native-mqtt/android/build.gradle'
>   line: 36 [stderr]
> - What went wrong: [stderr]  A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-mqtt'. [stderr]
>
> > Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.facebook.react:react-native:0.19.+] on object of type
> > org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
> > [stderr]
>
> - Try: [stderr]
>
> > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. [stderr]
> > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. [stderr]
> > Run with --scan to get full insights. [stderr]
>
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org [stderr]  BUILD FAILED in 3m 14s Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it
>   incompatible with Gradle 8.0. You can use '--warning

Could someone help me to solve this issue please!

Answer (score 0):

So, a couple things.
I'll assume you followed the instructions well enough from the [docs](https://docs.expo.dev/build/setup/) to get to this point. The first error shows you what to do in your app.json, which is remove `android.package` entry.

The second thing is the package you appear to be using. It has not been actively maintained for a while and the numerous issues show it to have a problem which is why you have that gradlew error shown. A better library may be this one linked [here](https://github.com/davesters/rn-native-mqtt). I haven't tested it though so YMMV.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, pls why I should remove the package name?!

Comment: It's been deprecated for a while in eas-cli. See the pull-request [here](https://github.com/expo/eas-cli/pull/407)